# Poco::LocalDateTime::timestamp() not converting timestamps to UTC

Tags: poco-libraries

According to the header file of `Poco::Timestamp`, timestamps are in UTC, see [Timestamp documentation](https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Timestamp.html). If timestamps are in UTC, shouldn't a method converting a `Poco::LocalDateTime` to `Poco::Timestamp` make sure that the returned timestamp is in UTC? Currently, `Poco::LocalDateTime::timestamp()` does not do this, and the returned timestamp is in local time.

It's especially strange since the assignment operator `Poco::LocalDateTime::operator = (const Timestamp& timestamp)` does a UTC to local time conversion. The following code asserts because of this:

```
Poco::LocalDateTime local1 = Poco::LocalDateTime( 2020, 1, 30 );
Poco::Timestamp timestamp = local1.timestamp();
Poco::LocalDateTime local2 = timestamp;
assert( local1 == local2 );
```

`local1` will not have the same value as `local2` in this example. Am I the only one who think this is strange behavior?

Comment: A workaround: `Poco::Timestamp timestampFromLocalTime = Poco::Timestamp::fromUtcTime( Poco::LocalDateTime( 1970, 1, 1 ).utcTime() );`

Comment: If you look at `LocalDateTime::timestamp()` you will see that it converts the timestamp before returning via `Timestamp::fromUtcTime` so that function returns a Timestamp in Local time, not UTC time.

Comment: You can use the `Timestamp::utcTime()` function or the `Timestamp::raw()` function but those return different types to prevent you from accidentally doing the wrong thing.  What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: @cookie-butter, You say: *"that function returns a Timestamp in Local time"*. The documentation says: *"Timestamps are UTC"*. That's my point.

Comment: Yes, I see what you mean now.  I think this has to with the determineTzd function.  When a LocalDateTime is constructed from a Timestamp, it determines the _tzd from the OS.  That delta could be slightly off for the 2 LocalDateTime objects.  You might need to have a tolerance on your equality check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at `LocalDateTime::timestamp()` you will see that it converts the timestamp before returning via `Timestamp::fromUtcTime` so that function returns a Timestamp in Local time, not UTC time.

You can use the `Timestamp::utcTime()` function or the `Timestamp::raw()` function but those return different types to prevent you from accidentally doing the wrong thing.

What are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: The user selects a time (in local time) in the user interface. This time needs to be converted to a UTC timestamp and stored in the database. My question is not how to do the conversion, instead it is about the behavior of Poco's `.timestamp()` relative to what is specified in the documentation.

Comment: I am sorry if I misunderstood.  You can use `LocalDateTime::utc()` or `LocalDateTime::utcTime()` to get the utc time of the LocalDateTime.